# Why delete also the instructive answer to: In 'inasmuch', what did 'in', 'as', 'much' mean?

Tags: discussion, reopen

3 users deleted [my question](https://ell.stackexchange.com/a/62983/8712) and ergo also the instructive answer, with 4 upvotes, that would aid all other ELLs here. Why not retain the question, simply to allow others to profit from the merit of the answer?

Comment: They decided the question isn't worth keeping, as it **doesn't help future ELLers**. What *you* have to do is to prove to us that question is worth keeping.

Comment: The problem is that the question is off-topic here, even though you found the answer helpful. It's also the same as a question on EL&U, and while it's unfortunate you didn't get a useful answer there, that doesn't really make it on-topic here. Maybe you could twist the arm of @StoneyB and get him to post his answer to http://english.stackexchange.com/q/258281/80039

Comment: Another option would be to migrate it to ELU and merge it into the other question if they are, in fact, similar... Or, at the very least, make it a dupe.

Comment: An off-topic question is off-topic, whether the answers are good or not. Questions that are not on-topic _should_ be deleted unless they can be edited to be on-topic. Closed questions with upvoted answers are not generally deleted automatically - that doesn't mean they shouldn't be deleted at all.

Answer (score 6):

The question was closed 6 weeks ago, had a score of -4, and had not been edited into an appropriate form in the ample time since it's closure. Off-topic questions which are not edited to become on-topic are eventually going to be deleted, if the system is working as it should.

If the answer hadn't gotten 4 upvotes, the question would actually [have been auto-deleted by the system](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/92006/187816) due to its negative score. Upvoting answers to closed questions is a separate problem, and one that really hasn't harmed ELL specifically (though I know it's been an issue on other sites in the network). And the upvotes could have been placed prior to the closure, and without regard to the topicality of the question. That doesn't make the question on-topic or useful, and our users deleting those questions is part of the community clean-up process that SE is founded upon.

You have a lot of questions, some with quite a few upvotes and answers. I think it could be helpful to look through your questions that got positive feedback and see what they have in common, and what separates them from closed/deleted questions. If you cannot see why a particular question has been marked as off-topic, it may be useful to you to post a meta question along the lines of "How can I improve this question so that it would be on-topic?" and see about getting the question re-opened.